# Can't get C# syntax highlighting to work

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I have just posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156924/naming-user-controls-without-default-constructors-in-xaml) on StackOverflow. At the bottom there is some C# code which I would like to display with syntax hightlighting. I tried to add a hightlighting direction, like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
[four blanks]using System.Windows.Controls;  
[more indented code]
```

but I could not make it work. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You will need [one blank line] before [four blanks]

Comment: Thanks, YOU! That worked. If you post this as an answer I'll make it the accepted answer.

Comment: ok, added as answer.

Comment: Your question needs to have the correct tags to get syntax highlighting first of all...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will need [one blank line] before [four blanks], like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->

[four blanks]using System.Windows.Controls;  
[more indented code]
```